# rndc not working on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, bind

Hello I have issue with rndc on FreeBSD.I have installed named on jail and I created `rndc.conf` file.When I type rndc it is working,but when I type rndc *something* it is not working and shows :`rndc: no key for server and no default` .
Here is my config files

**rndc-key.conf**

```
key "rndc-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "09m6WDaq60aTaK0eiZilxyw2npx7iy9zbtw1g4wLZcY=";
};
```

**named.conf**

```
include "/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/rndc-key.conf";
```

And when I type : `rndc -k /usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/rndc-key.conf status`  it shows:

```
WARNING: key file (/usr/local/etc/namedb/conf/rndc-key.conf) exists, but using default configuration file (/bind//etc/namedb/rndc.conf)
rndc: no key for server and no default
```

But I can't find any config file where include  `/bind//etc/namedb/rndc.conf` .

Please help